# Powershell script to export to two different files then run a seperate command for either of those (Active and inActive)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am complete n00b with Powershell,

I have done some googling and places like Stackoverflow but cannot for the life of me require what I need.
So as per my link below, I have a file that is sent to me every night called Extracts.

In this file, I have a number of columns (A - H).

One of these columns includes information for a user that is inActive, Active or Suspended (Column F).

The other column I need is the staff's individual number (this is in Column D).

Example:

```
    D         F
60090459 | InActive
60137029 | Active
60137029 | Suspended
```

I need to have both InActive and Active output to seperate files and then either add the user to a group or remove the user from a group, say the group name is "testgroup".

Unfortunatly I don't have any example code, as everything I have searched for on google does not have exactly what I am after.

The code is below:

```
$results = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\SmileExtracts\test_smile_22apr2022.csv | Group-Object -Property Status 
ForEach-Object {

$Inactive = $_.Group |

Where-Object {

$_.Status -eq 'Inactive'

}}

Where-Object {

Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status

[pscustomobject]@{

'Status' = $_.Name

'ClientInstalled' = $Inactive

'Stafflink2' = $Stafflink2

}

}
#outputs the results
$Result | Export-CSV "C:\temp\Extracts.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I would like to output 2 results 'Active' and 'inactive' as well for the sake of auditing.

Thank You very much :D

[a sample list of the file we need to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4eCE.png)

EDIT: for those that are complaining about 'script for service', you all need to go away, you need to read that I have looked for examples and tried my own code without fail.

Comment: Hi, this is the code I currently have, it's not much but... it's based off:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1475239-count-unique-values-in-csv
<code>
$results = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\SmileExtracts\test_smile_22apr2022.csv | Group-Object -Property Status 
ForEach-Object {

$Inactive = $_.Group |

Where-Object {

$_.Status -eq 'Inactive'

}}

Where-Object {

Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status

[pscustomobject]@{

'Status' = $_.Name

'ClientInstalled' = $Inactive

'Stafflink2' = $Stafflink2

}

}

$results
</code>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As you have noticed, code in a comment becomes unreadable.. [edit] your question and paste it in there as formatted text

Comment: @Maddog351 - please DO NOT post images of data/errors/code. why? lookee ... Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Can you add to your original question the output to `import-csv C:\Scripts\SmileExtracts\test_smile_22apr2022.csv | select -first 2`    don't forget to replace sensitive data with xxxxxxx's or whatever

Comment: Your code is unreadable. You could do something like `Import-csv c:\file.csv | where status -eq "Inactive" | select name, status, stafflink | export-csv -header status,"client installed",stafflink2 c:\inactive.csv` add a second line replacing inactive with active. Problem is I don't know what your csv headers are or where they go. You can also set import-csv headers. Your code is very confusing

Comment: I don't know where $stafflink2 comes from. And so on. We want to help but need a more complete understanding of your attempt.

Comment: The $Stafflink2  is one of the columns.

LastName, FirstName, StafflinkID1, StafflinkID2, Description, Status (InAcitve, Active, Suspended), Comment, AccessType

Thanks for the attempt for the code, I will have a look tonight.